# Appium ideviceinstaller could not initialize

Tags: javascript, ios, node.js, appium

I have a problem after starting the Appium server as:

```
/Applications/Appium.app/Contents/Resources/node/bin/node /Applications/Appium.app/Contents/Resources/node_modules/appium/bin/appium.js
```

And trying to connect a device I get the following error.

```
A new session could not be created. (Original error: Could not initialize ideviceinstaller; make sure it is installed and works on your system) (33)
```

Appium log:

```
←[36minfo←[39m: [debug] Couldn't find ideviceinstaller, trying built-in at /Applications/Appium.app/Contents/Resources/node_modules/appium/build/libimobiledevice-macosx/ideviceinstaller
←[31merror←[39m: Could not initialize ideviceinstaller; make sure it is installed and works on your system
←[31merror←[39m: Failed to start an Appium session, err was: Error: Could not initialize ideviceinstaller; make sure it is installed and works on your system
←[36minfo←[39m: [debug] Error: Could not initialize ideviceinstaller; make sure it is installed and works on your system
←[36minfo←[39m: [debug] Responding to client with error: {"status":33,"value":{"message":"A new session could not be created. (Original error: Could not initialize ideviceinstaller; make sure it is installed and works on your system)","orig Value":"Could not initialize ideviceinstaller; make sure it is installed and works on your system"},"sessionId":null}
←[36minfo←[39m: ←[37m<-- POST /wd/hub/session ←[39m←[31m500←[39m←[90m 1252.938 ms - 300←[39m ←[90m←[39m
```

Did anyone encounter this problem? I use `Appium 1.4.8` and is launched on a mac via `ssh`, using `putty`.

Comment: Look like the ideviceinstaller was not installed. Please use command line: "brew install ideviceinstaller --HEAD" to install it

Comment: I've done it and is the same. From the log I see that is trying to use the ideviceinstaller from the Appim.app place, not the one installed via brew

Comment: Try command "ideviceinstaller -help" to make sure your ideviceinstaller working

Comment: When typing command "ideviceinstaller -help" I get the followings:

Usage: ideviceinstaller OPTIONS
Manage apps on iOS devices.

  -u, --udid UDID Target specific device by its 40-digit device UDID.
  -l, --list-apps List apps, possible options:
       -o list_user - list user apps only (this is the default)
       -o list_system - list system apps only

Comment: Did you try to launch "Doctor"?

Comment: I lunched appium doctor, and it's all right, but i'm not using GUI, I'm run the appium server through nodejs

Comment: And if I lunch the Appium.app my tests are working. The only issue is when lunching appium with nodejs. Did anyone encounter this behavior?

Comment: After testing I found that, opening on my mac Appium via node js works just fine, the problem appears when I'm doing ssh after my pc, that's the moment when ideviceinstaller is not initialize

Instruments must be as Environmental Variable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On OSX (10.11, El Capitan), following part of the advice given on https://github.com/appium/appium/issues/4584 I was able to run past this problem.

- Install Appium first ([from .dmg](https://bitbucket.org/appium/appium.app/downloads/)). In case you have it installed, uninstall and re-install.
- If don't have it already, install [Homebrew](http://brew.sh/) (in case you have it installed, skip this).
- Install ideviceinstaller: `brew install --HEAD ideviceinstaller` (if you had it installed, first remove with `brew uninstall ideviceinstaller`)

Answer (score 0):

Please try

```
sudo xcode-select -switch /Applications/<installed via brew>.app/Contents/Developer/
```

Comment: xcode was set correct. The problem was from ./bash_profile and bashrc. The path was set to instruments only in bash_profile not into bashrc